# SQL syntax error when updating password

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP/MySQL - SQL syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875747/php-mysql-sql-syntax-error)

I am trying to update a user password with the below script, however I am just getting the following error. I have been using PHP and MySQL for only about 2 months now so am still a beginner so I would really appreciate any comments regarding my below code. Thank you in advance for your help.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(password, salt) VALUES (
>   'fcf829e6c3478752799b7d49798a14640f110dd4f8767' at line 1

```
<?php

//Pull in form info

$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

//Chrck if the 2 password fields match
if($pass1 != $pass2) {
    header('Location: ../admin/pass-change.php?pw=notmatched');
    die();
}

//encrypts the password

$hash = hash('sha256', $pass1);

//creates a 3 character sequence

function createSalt()
{
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);

//initialise connection with databse

require_once('../Connections/EliteGrooming.php');

mysql_select_db($database_EliteGrooming, $EliteGrooming);

//Execute the query

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$query = "UPDATE admin_users (password, salt)
        VALUES ( '$hash', '$salt' )
        WHERE username = '$username';";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
mysql_close();
header('Location: ../admin/pass-change.php?PassChanged');

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, it should be

```
UPDATE admin_users 
   SET password = '$hash', 
        salt = '$salt' 
WHERE username = '$username'
```

beware, your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please the article below

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have added $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); to my code, is this enough to prevent SQL injection?

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like the input password somehow has ' added before and after the entry. Translated you are putting into the database:

```
 $query = "UPDATE admin_users (password, salt)
    VALUES ( ''f124782349023589270365fhjdhf2893'', '$salt' )
    WHERE username = '$username';";
```

The reason I say this is because it only returns one value input. That or your salt is not being found.

EDIT: Above has it right. your missing the SET command.